# Expanding a variable, #cmakedefine, and generator expression in template file

Tags: cmake

I have the following template

### config.c.in

```
#define QPID_DISPATCH_VERSION "${QPID_DISPATCH_VERSION}"
#define QPID_DISPATCH_LIB "$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:qpid-dispatch>"
#cmakedefine01 USE_MEMORY_POOL
```

And I wish to obtain the following, by expanding the variable, #cmakedefine, and generator expression.

### config.c

```
#define QPID_DISPATCH_VERSION "1.6.0-SNAPSHOT"
#define QPID_DISPATCH_LIB "libqpid-dispatch.so"
#define USE_MEMORY_POOL 1
```

The problem is, there does not seem to be a CMake function which can expand all three.

### What I can do is

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h.tmp)
file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h INPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h.tmp)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a temporary file? Cleaning up the file is tricky, because file GENERATE does not run immediately.

Comment: I think that piping `configure_file` and `file(GENERATE)` is the best way. As you correctly note, `file(GENERATE)` works at the end of configuration stage, where all "common" variables are lost. With very small configuration file one may store this content inside `CMakeLists.txt` and use `string(CONFIGURE)` combined with `file(GENERATE ... CONTENT)`, but multiline strings are so ugly in CMake.

Comment: I did not know about `string(CONFIGURE)`. I believe if I load the .in file into variable, then I can first `string(CONFIGURE)` and then write it out using `file(GENERATE)` without creating a temp file. It should even work in CMake 2.8.12 which must be supported by project. I'll see what I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Tsyvarev's comment, I now have

```
file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in" CONFIG_H_IN)
string(CONFIGURE "${CONFIG_H_IN}" CONFIG_H_TMP)
file(GENERATE OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h" CONTENT "${CONFIG_H_TMP}")
```

Comment: BTW, if you want to post this as answer yourself, I'd accept that and delete this one.